# Merge [serial-voting] with [tactical-downvoting]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, retag-request, synonym-request, meta

Should we merge [serial-voting](/questions/tagged/serial-voting) with [tactical-downvoting](/questions/tagged/tactical-downvoting)?

Serial voting has the following excerpt:

> Serial voting is the act of serially (repeatedly) up or downvoting another user's posts over a (usually short) period of time.

It has no tag description, 133 questions, mostly about serial downvoting, but some about upvotes as well.

Tactical downvoting has the following excerpt:

> Tactical downvoting is when a user downvotes huge amounts of another users questions and answers. This is also the same as voting fraud and serial down-voting.

It has only 13 questions, but quite a long description about serial voting and voting fraud, and one of the Q&A questions the description refers to is tagged [serial-voting](/questions/tagged/serial-voting), and not [tactical-downvoting](/questions/tagged/tactical-downvoting).

Having both tags seems redundant to me. While one is more specific than the other, most questions about serial downvotes use the less specific [serial-voting](/questions/tagged/serial-voting).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The tag wiki for "tactical downvoting" is wrong IMO. "Tactical downvoting" is downvoting someone else's answers to end up higher in the list. Apparently, discouraging this was the reason that answer downvotes cost a point.

So instead of merging these tags, we should change the "tactical downvoting" tag wiki to have its original meaning. We might do a bit of question cleanup after that.

Comment: Rolled them back, feel free to suggest a wiki for that.

Comment: @BhargavRao Thanks, done!

Comment: Needs some usage guidance as well. (*use this here ... use [serial voting] instead in these cases ...")

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Knowing that, I agree we shouldn't merge them.