# Is it okay to tactically downvote (downvoting competing answers)?

Tags: discussion, voting, tactical-downvoting

When you downvote an answer, you lose 1 reputation. According to [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/363887/13517701), this is to discourage tactical/strategic downvoting, where you downvote other competing answers to a question to bring you up higher on this list, as to increase the likelyhood of your question getting accepted and/or upvoted. Because you personally lose some reputation from tactical downvoting, is it ok to do so from time to time?

Comment: Vote on the content. Period.

Comment: When you vote on anything else than the quality of the content, this is counter-productive for the whole site.

Comment: Of course not! Did you really think you might get an affirmative answer here? Do enough of it and the system will catch you. Definition of "enough" is not publicly disclosed either

Comment: Talk about breaking the steak of poorly received questions :) Was your intention to get into the pantheon of DVed questions on Meta? More on topic, I'd say `-1` is a useless penalty that does not fulfill its purpose (-1 against gaining +10 for each UV on your answer and an extra +15 upon accept - someone certainly missed a couple of lessons on game theory) while discouraging well-intentioned users who just dislike being punished for what they perceive as helping the site. Apart from that, there is only one comment: NO, NEVER.

Comment: You really think that you will get accepted simply because you are on the top of the list ... I don't think the OP is *stupid* enough to only consider the order in order to accept an answer.

Comment: "Is it OK to mislead users as to the usefulness to one solution only to try and embellish the usefulness of another one?" Well, no. You're free *not* to vote, if you wish. It's only natural to expect your own solution to be better than others posted on the same question but unless the others are actually *bad*, please don't downvote them.

Comment: Don't compete, cooperate instead.

Comment: That's funny voting on Meta. We say that voting on Meta can "express agreement/disagreement with the proposal", but .. there is **no proposal** in this question post! The post just asks what is good and what is bad. The asker doesn't event state that he/she used tactical downvoting or want to use it. OK, let's put aside these downvotes.. but why these close votes?? The question is clear, it is definitely about how Stack Overflow works and it is definitely can be answered.

Comment: @Tsyvarev agreed. Questions with a high level of red alert just can't be treated neutrally by everyone. Keep in mind that those close votes are coming from individuals, it is not a group decision.

Comment: @Tsyvarev The question literally asks "**Is it okay to tactically downvote** (downvoting competing answers)?" The post's downvotes signal a stiff "NO" without needing to read a single answer. The proposal by OP was an attempt to establish precedence and community acceptance of a bad practice. Had they phrased their question more along the lines of "Does tactical downvoting exist?" then things would have likely turned out much much different.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: "The proposal by OP was an attempt to establish precedence and community acceptance of a bad practice." - Hmm, this is not what I feel when read the question. "Had they phrased their question more along the lines of "Does tactical downvoting exist?"" - This would be a strange question. If we (SO) have a mechanism against something, then this "something" definitely **exists**. Why ask about *existence* if you definitely know that it exists?

Comment: @Tsyvarev the last part of the last sentence ("is it ok to do so from time to time") might make it look to some like they have ulterior motives (given the OPs history on meta, that's unlikely, but not everyone track that). Also, the DVs are totally in alignment with the premise ("is it ok?" -> "no"). But as for the close votes, I agree with you, the "opinion-based" reason here is bs. I hope this is a bad joke - folks, we do not close posts on Meta for opinions!

Comment: ^ unless the close votes follow [this notion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/360772/11407695), which is kinda understandable, but  with the current wording (and presumed intention) it is a hell of a confusing closure choice on Meta and IMHO should not be used like this.

Comment: "Also, the DVs are totally in alignment with the premise ("is it ok?" -> "no")." - So, would the asker change the *alignment* - "is it bad ...?" - the voters should immediately **reverse** their votes? :) I hardly can imagine how to ask that question in *neutral alignment*, so no one could interpret "the asker likes that" or "the asker doesn't like that". (These are just my feelings. I perfectly understand previous comments and reasoning.)

Comment: @Tsyvarev - yup, that's why the votes are unlocked after editing (that's actually [happened before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334551/786798)). That aside, such an edit would be rolled back in the first place, because it invalidates other answers in this Q&A. So yes, I think normal votes are perfectly in alignment with what the OP is asking about. What I don't get is the close votes as opinion-based. P.s. Neutral wording for that would be "What are the reasons behind X" or "Why would anyone do Y" but this would only lead to a perfectly justified dupe closure.

Comment: "such an edit would be rolled back in the first place, because it invalidates other answers in this Q&A." - Such an edit would invalidate the [Dharman's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/406289/3440745), but only because that answer uses the very **short resolution** "No!". Would the answer start with "No, tactical downvoting is not OK", then it would immune to the alignment changings in the question. So, it is more problem with the answer, than with the question's *alignment*. E.g., [another answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/406300/3440745) doesn't depend from alignment at all.

Comment: @Tsyvarev "*We say that voting on Meta can "express agreement/disagreement with the proposal", but .. there is no proposal in this question post!*" I voted not in accordance with my agreement. I voted in accordance to how well researched the post is. As it happens, I would have probably voted the same if it was an FR. It shows *complete misunderstanding of SO and its purpose*. How would you vote on such a question? Would you say it's helpful? I wouldn't.

Comment: @Tsyvarev - not sure if you are mildly trolling or are serious :) But more on point: no matter how answers are aligned, if a single one is invalidated by an edit, the edit is bad and is eligible for a rollback. Also: "other answers in this Q&A" referred to a set of one with a possibility for extension, not to all "all answers in this Q&A".

Answer (score 36, accepted):

## No!

By using your votes for anything else than content rating, you waste time and abuse the system. Don't do this. **Only cast your vote based on the usefulness of any given post.**

Comment: Sadly while I agree with your sentiment, it's just not True. The only thing you explicitly cannot do on this site w/r/t voting is Serial downvote a particular user. You are, sadly, totally free to downvote whatever else you want, "abusing" the system or not. So should you, NO. Can you, Yes: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255460/4333359

Answer (score 5):

If your answer only looks good when a different answer looks bad then you're not Stack Overflowing properly.

In a sea of sub-par answers your tactic might work in the short run but writing an outstanding answer usually works best. Yes, there is a ["Fastest Gun in the West"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9731/235923) aspect but that usually applies for the popular tags.

You can strive to answer niche questions in your favorite programming language by being selective with your preferred tags.

Feverously answering a question which is so easy that 10 other answers come in isn't beneficial to the site nor your professional growth.